# no friction in blender game

Tags: game-engine, physics

With blender 2.78 I can't find how to remove friction between a cube (rigid body) and a plane (static).  I tried remove the damping, but that didn't help. I found things about anisotropic friction but not general friction.
I'm a beginner with Blender Game Engine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I answer my question. It was easy. Just have to make *Material* > *Physics*> *friction* to 0.000.